# Calling a parameterized callback function within a mongoose async callback function becomes 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, mongodb, callback, mongoose, scope

I am having a weird problem with calling a callback inside another callback from mongoose.
Setup : MEAN Stack.

```
myFunc = function (cb) {
        var projection = {
        '_id': 0,
        'var1': 1,
        'var2': 1
    }

    var order = {
        'var1': 1
    }

    User.find({})
        .select(projection).sort(order)
        .exec(function(err, docs){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                cb(err,docs);
            } else {
                console.log(docs);
                cb(err,docs);
            }
        });
};
```

going to the lines where cb(err,docs) will result in 
"ReferenceError: cb is not defined"

---

the weird part is 
I have functions with even deeper nested callbacks that can invoke the "cb" normaly.

```
myFunc = function(cb){
    model1.count({var1:'test'}, function (err, count) {
        if(count) {
            model2.findOne({dat1:'hoho'}, function (err, doc){
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    cb(err,doc);
                } else {
                    cb(err,doc);
                }
            });                 
        } else {
            cb({message: "No items found"}, null);
        }    
    })
}
```

The code above will be invoked like so...

```
function init(something){
    myfunc(function(err, doc) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err.message);
        } else {
            //do something about doc
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: so, where's the cb function? that's why it's saying cb is not defined.

Comment: The cb function will be called by another object or script. example is

function init(something){
    myfunc(function(err, doc) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err.message);
        } else {
            //do something about doc
        }
    });
}

*please see changes in question

Comment: *what I mean is... the cb is an anonymous function passed by the method invokation. (see last part of question where the myFunc() is invoked)

Answer (score 0):

ugh, it seems that the calling function did not properly follow the rules.

it called

```
myFunc(json, function(err,doc){
    //do something
})
```

wrong param count...